# Inserta valor en tabla y obtener automaticamente el ID de registro que tendra

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy realizando una insercion a una base de datos y quisiera que automaticamente luego del INSERT el archivo PHP obtuviera el ID que le correspondera al registro (ID_PLANILLA).

Esto lo necesito ya que automaticamente debo mostrar una grafica con los datos obtenidos.

EH pensado en algo como obtener el ultimo ID en la base de datos y sumarle 1, pero no se como hacerlo.

PHP insert:

```
  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO sanciones (
          unidad,
          cedula_sancionado,
          cedula_sancionador, 
          cedula_superior,
          articulo_falta, 
          aparte_falta, 
          documento_seleccion,
          fecha_inicio, 
          fecha_termino, 
          dias_sancion, 
          aclaratoria_sancion, 
          estado_sancion_id,
          medida_id,
          articulo_circunstancias,
          agravante_seleccion, 
          atenuante_seleccion, 
          total_medida,
          total_demerito_final, 
          estado_lugar_id) 
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("siiiiisssisiiissddi", 
      $unidad,
      $cedula1, 
      $cedula2, 
      $cedula3, 
      $articulo_falta, 
      $aparte_falta, 
      $documentos_implode, 
      $fecha_inicio, 
      $fecha_termino, 
      $dias, 
      $aclaratoria, 
      $estado_sancion_id, 
      $tipo_medida, 
      $tipo_circunstancia, 
      $agravantes_implode, 
      $atenuantes_implode, 
      $total_medida, 
      $total_demerito_final, 
      $lugar);
      $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt)
      {
$idplanilla= lastid
      echo ('<script>alert("Datos insertados satisfactoriamente!");</script>');
      echo ("<script>window.location = 'grafica_unidades.php?idplanilla=<?=$idplanillla?>"
      $stmt->close();
      }
      else
      {
      echo ('<script>alert("No se pudo generar la OMD");</script>');
      echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_generar_omd_unidades.php';</script>");
      }
```

Comment: Chécate este ejemplo de w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: @MarcosGallardo intente lo que publico lixus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La clase `mysqli` ofrece una propiedad llamada [`insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php).

> El valor de el campo **AUTO_INCREMENT** que fué actualizado por la consulta anterior. Devuelve cero si no hubo una consulta previa en la conexión o si la consulta no actualiza un valor **AUTO_INCREMENT**.
>
> **Nota:** Si el número es mayor que el valor máximo int, `mysqli_insert_id()` retornará un string.

También vale la pena resaltar que la clase `mysqli_stmt` también ofrece la misma propiedad llamada [`insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php), pero:

> Debe tenerse en cuenta que el uso de `mysqli_stmt->insert_id` no dará lugar a que se devuelva un ID único para cada ejecución de una instrucción de inserto preparada. En la práctica, parece que se devuelve el primer ID de inserción. Si está realizando múltiples inserciones con la misma instrucción preparada (una invocación de `mysqli_stmt::prepare` y varias invocaciones de `mysqli_stmt::execute()` para una sentencia dada), y necesita mantener el ID exclusivo para cada inserto, use `mysqli_connection->insert_id`.

Aplicado a tu código sería así:

```
//...
$total_demerito_final, 
$lugar);

if ($stmt->execute()) { // <-- AQUI tenias un error
  $idplanilla = $stmt->insert_id; // <-- AQUI obtenemos el ID
  //...
```

**NOTA:** la sentencia `if($stmt)` siempre será `truly`, es por esta razón que deberías reescribirla como lo he hecho en mi código.

Comment: lo deje asi: if ($stmt)
  {
  $id_omd = $stmt->insert_id; // <-- AQUI obtenemos el ID

Porque si coloco if($stmt->execute()) no se porque, genera doble insert.

o deberia borrar el execute anterior al if y dejar solo el del if?

Comment: @Victor-Random, tenes que dejar un solo `execute` y en este caso solo el del `if`